# How to keep component in sync with AsyncStorage?

Tags: react-native

So I need to get a value from async storage to build my component UI and no problem with that. But, in another component I'll be changing this async storage value, but once I do it, I need the other component to re render and get the updated value from async storage.

I know that this can be done in react web using local storage but that's just possible because local storage provides an event listener which fires whenever it changes, but there is no way to attach an event listener to async storage.

So my question is, is this even possible to do? And if not, any suggestions on how to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with async storage, but typically you will use the observer pattern through a library like RxJS in Javascript.
Basically you create an observable to which you subscribe, and subsequently the observer gets notified of state updates to the observable.

You can check out the source code of this library that I just found for an example: 
https://github.com/bassihassan/xreactive-react-native-storage/blob/master/index.js

Comment: I don't think this is going to work, it doesn't seem like the value will keep coming updated as I update in other component, but I will try this anyway and see if works and if so, I accept your answer

Comment: @GustavoMendonça The idea is that you can subscribe to updates on the store, and that views have the ability to update themselves when they receive an event. Good luck, it should be possible although I haven't done the implementation myself.